# How can I reduce space size in mintline?

Tags: minted

I want to reduce default space size mintline. But when I type `\hphantom` inside the `mintline`, it written as string.

code:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}
\setminted[bash]{fontsize=\scriptsize}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\, \newline
\mintinline{bash}{$ cd / \} \newline
\mintinline{bash}{$}\,\mintinline{bash}{cd / \}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Second line is the wanted version where space is applied as `\,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce *all* spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}
\setminted[bash]{fontsize=\scriptsize,formatcom=\spaceskip0.2em\relax}

\begin{document}

\mintinline{bash}{$ cd / \}

\setminted[bash]{fontsize=\scriptsize,formatcom=}

\mintinline{bash}{$ cd / \}

\end{document}
```

Below is the standard.

[image]

If you need to switch between the two versions, you can use `\newmintinline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}

\newmintinline[bashnormal]{bash}{fontsize=\scriptsize}
\newmintinline[bashreduced]{bash}{
  fontsize=\scriptsize,
  formatcom=\spaceskip0.2em\relax
}

\begin{document}

\bashnormal{$ cd / \}

\bashreduced{$ cd / \}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before.

Or, for occasional use of the reduced spaces

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{vs}

\setminted[bash]{fontsize=\scriptsize}

\begin{document}

\mintinline[formatcom=\spaceskip0.2em\relax]{bash}{$ cd / \}

\mintinline{bash}{$ cd / \}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to define two independent `bash` one with normal space and other with reduced space?

Comment: @alper Yes, see edited answer

Comment: thans I appreciated your edit.